# matplotlib to combine lower bins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I am new to matplotlib and trying to plot a histogram. I am interested in lower bin range and hence split my bin range, but it looks kind of ugly with a lot of white space in the right side.
I have some code that generates this histogram but I want to change it such that:

- combine all bars after xaxis position 150 as 150+ so that lower range bars are shown better.
- change the color of bars
- leftmost bar to a different color
- bars that represent x axis ticks between 5-40 have different color
- bars from 40+ different colors

  ```
  import matplotlib
  matplotlib.use('PS')
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  # sample data, These are not actual values since I have a large csv file  
  # with 1000's of rows.
  values=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,111,12,23,30,30,35,353,35,25,25,25,15,15,15,20,20,20,40,40,40,45,50,55,50,50,100,200,300,400]

  limit1, limit2 = 50, 500
  binwidth1, binwidth2 = 5, 100
  binr=list(range(0, limit1, binwidth1)) + list(range(100, limit2, binwidth2))
  n, bins, patches=plt.hist(values, bins = binr)
  one, fifty = np.percentile(values, [0.5,50])
  for patch, rightside, leftside in zip(patches, bins[1:], bins[:-1]):
      if rightside < one:
          patch.set_facecolor('green')
      elif leftside > fifty:
          patch.set_facecolor('red')
  plt.title("Frequency Histogram")
  plt.xlabel("Word Count")
  plt.ylabel("Frequency")
  plt.savefig(plot_file)
  plt.close()
  ```

[image]

Comment: Kudos (upvote) for making a small example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear about what you're attempting to do, especially that your expectations seem to be a bit contradictory to your simple example (I mean the percentile-based colouring).

Anyway, I suggest that you use `np.histogram` directly (since you have `numpy` imported already), and call `plt.bar` manually. The main advantage of this (besides taking better control of the output, at the cost of some minor increase in effort) is that you can pass a list containing the colour of each bar.

A modified version of your example:

```
values=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,111,12,23,30,30,35,353,35,25,25,25,15,15,15,20,20,20,40,40,40,45,50,55,50,50,100,200,300,400]

limit1, limit2 = 50, 500
binwidth1, binwidth2 = 5, 100
binr=list(range(0, limit1, binwidth1)) + list(range(100, limit2, binwidth2))

# improvement 1: merge bins above 150, keep the same maximum
thresh = 150
# keep the first value after the threshold too
binr_tmp = [val for val in binr if val<=thresh] 
binr = binr_tmp + [binr[len(binr_tmp)], binr[-1]]

# improvement 2: use np.histogram explicitly, feed into plt.bar later (for colors)
bin_vals, bins = np.histogram(values, bins=binr)
bins_left = binr[:-1]
bins_width = np.diff(bins)
bins_right = bins_left + bins_width
one, fifty = np.percentile(values, [0.5,50])

# "change the color of bars": you did the same thing earlier
# improvement: use a numpy.array for a colour list, set for each bar separately
# (possibility for array indexing)
# just don't forget to turn into a list() when calling plt.bar
bins_color = np.array(['blue']*len(bins_left), dtype=object)
bins_color[bins_left>fifty] = 'red'
bins_color[bins_left+bins_width<one] = 'green'

# "leftmost bar to a different color":
bins_color[0] = 'magenta'

# "bars from 40+ different color": would conflict with percentile-based original version
thresh2 = 40
#bins_color[bins_right>thresh2] = 'olive'

hbars = plt.bar(left=bins_left, height=bin_vals, width=bins_width, color=list(bins_color))
plt.title("Frequency Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Word Count")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
#plt.savefig(plot_file)
#plt.close()
plt.show()
```

I tried to leave informative comments. The main thing to note is that `np.histogram` generates the bin values, which are fed into `plt.bar`. The latter has a bit more complicated input compared to `plt.hist` (in particular, the left and right side of each bar has to be specified manually), but this also allows for much greater customization.

As you can see with "improvement 1", I merged your bins above the `thresh` value, leaving the others intact. I know you asked for this in order to leave more space for your `x<50` region. You can do this by manually shifting the last value of `binr`, pulling your last (merged) bar tighter. If you do this, you should use `plt.xlabel` to indicate this on the x axis.

The reason that I did *not* do this is that manipulations like this strongly distort your data, leading to a lot of bias. You should generally avoid doing this. If you're intent on visually distorting the bars and you're OK with this, just do what I wrote in the previous paragraph.

I'm including the result of the above, of course the differences are not that huge compared to the original. However, I believe that most manipulations you want to do are much easier with the introduction of the `bins_color` `array`.

[image: output]